# Track URL ends with .jpg or .png with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I 'm trying to Track URL like this :

```
http://example.com/dir1/img1.jpg
```

And i don't have the source code of this image website hosting , I only have text box form to put the URL of the image , plus it's only accepts links  that ends with  `.jpg` or `.png` ;

[image: Image URL Box]

And it shows the image URL in JQUERY POP-UP

So I have developed page that contains the image as `img src html tag` and put the script for Google Analytics account .

But the image is not shown cause it's not end with jpg or png file extension ?

So how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your only option would be a UTM code, but if what ever platform you're using blocks any string that doesn't end with an image extension, I'd say you're pretty stuck

Comment: If you host an image on your server, open the image in a browser and stick a UTM string on the end, what happens?

Comment: aka i will try it and tell you right now ..

Comment: The browser open it with no problems , but the UTM code works only with clicks not with view of the URL right ?

Comment: You'll need to test it. In your Campaign reporting section in Analytics see if it's registering sessions by viewing that URL. After some digging it doesn't look like it will. However, this should be a good backup option: http://forums.seochat.com/analytics-analysis-76/there-way-track-image-views-448672.html

Comment: It sounds that the solution in fourms work with image clicks not image views right ?